# kubuntu - DrRacket 5.1.3 doesn't work well

Tags: kubuntu, kde, libraries, kwin

I have ubuntu 12.04 with kde (latest version from ppa), I've installed DrRacket from repositories. 
It starts but I can't see menu, here is a picture:
[image]

Do you know why? Do I miss some lib or it's a kwin problem? 
Thanks

**edit**: ok here is the errors from terminal:

```
    drracket
Gdk: IA__gdk_window_thaw_updates: assertion `impl_window->update_freeze_count > 0' failed
Gdk: IA__gdk_window_thaw_updates: assertion `impl_window->update_freeze_count > 0' failed
```

Comment: Have you tried to launch the program from the konsole/terminal ? Are there error messages in the ~/.xsession-errors ? About KDE error messages: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?59067-Where-are-error-messages-from-programs-launched-from-the-K-menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When searching with the error message**

> Gdk: IA__gdk_window_thaw_updates: assertion
> `impl_window->update_freeze_count > 0' failed

A hit: http://racket-lang.org/irc-logs/20111018.txt

> 14:52 mithos28: There is a known bug with gnome 3.
>
> 14:52 mithos28: It is fixed in the nightlies, and will be in the release coming out soon.

**Versions**

Ubuntu packages: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=racket&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

The Precise has: 5.1.3

The latest Ubuntu packages version is: 5.3.1 (Raring)

--Edit--

Racket team PPA: [https://launchpad.net/~plt](https://launchpad.net/%7Eplt)

There are:

Racket

Racket Nightly

Racket Textual

--Edit--

**Ubuntu Bug reports**

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/racket/+bugs
--> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/racket/+bug/1065997

> Menus not shown in DrRacket GUI
>
> DistroRelease: Ubuntu 12.04
>
> Package: racket 5.1.3+dfsg1-1